# Submitting AJAX request using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

Here is my current code, I want to push an object (recipe) into an array at the server side, but I haven't even gotten that far yet. Right now I'm just trying to console.log(recipe) on server and getting undefined.

HTML:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning add-recipe'><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true" onclick='addRecipe(<%= JSON.stringify(recipe.author.id) %>)'></i></button>
```

JavaScript (client):

```
function addRecipe(recipe){
   var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var recipe = recipe;
   xml.open("POST", "/add-recipe", true);
   xml.send({recipe: recipe});
}
```

JavaScript (server):

```
router.post('/add-recipe', function(req, res) {
   var recipe = req.body.recipe;
   console.log(recipe);
})
```

Comment: At some point you'll have `JSON.stringify()` your data prior to sending it.

Comment: `xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')`. Also `var recipe = recipe` is not necessary; you already have variable named `recipe` passed to the function. You could do: `var recipe = JSON.stringify(recipe);`. Additionaly, just to be sure, `console.log(JSON.stringify(recipe, false, 2))` inside `addRecipe()` and [validate it](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I suggest using the Fetch API, XMLHttpRequest method is outdated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes are required in both frontend and back-end
Front-end changes

```
function addRecipe(recipe){
   var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var recipe = recipe;
   xml.open("POST", "/add-recipe", true);
   xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
   xml.send(JSON.stringify({recipe: recipe}));
}
```

For the backend to consume json in express you will have to use the body parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// I am assuming router the name of your express app 
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/add-recipe', function(req, res) {
   var recipe = req.body.recipe;
   console.log(recipe);
})
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you! Router was just a module route file and I had included require('body-parser') in main app.js file but had not included app.use(bodyParser.json());